# I want to create something similar to the img in Bootstrap. I need a divider in between that is shown in the img

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the code, I have created columns and a utility divider. I want to customize the vertical diver though. Here is the code.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 border-right">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-md-right ">Find Work</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-md-right">Find Contractor</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-md-right">Focus On Your Work</div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 text-md-right">Get Paid</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3 ">Find Contractors</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 ">Find Contractor</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Focus On Your Work</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 ">Get Paid</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it must be refined, but one approach is establishing some padding for the most inner `div`s and absolute positioning a circle in the inner div's in the right panel, so it's fixed near the top-left corner of each inner div. This is just an idea that must be worked out to get it responsive (you'll notice that I've removed the grid classes that took care of responsiveness).

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/julianobrasil/pen/WNQJdjN)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6 pr-lg-1 pl-lg-0">
      <div class="text-md-right">Find Work</div>
      <div class="text-md-right">Find Contractor</div>
      <div class="text-md-right">Focus On Your Work</div>
      <div class="text-md-right">Get Paid</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 pl-lg-1 pr-lg-0 right-pane">
      <div>
        <div class="circle"><div></div></div>
        Find Work
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="circle"><div></div></div>
        Find Contractor
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="circle"><div></div></div>
        Focus On Your Work
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="circle"><div></div></div>
        Get Paid
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 500px;
}

.row > div > div {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}

.right-pane > div {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -16px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #174658;
}

.circle > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  background-color: #174658;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

### The final result of the above styling is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked on responsiveness and it works fine now